# My Google script is throwing an "Unexpected string error"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am filling an array with some formulas to write as part of a data moving script. This line throws "unexpected string" error from Google Script when I try to save it:

```
var forms = [[,"=\"Week Averages\"","=iferror(round(average(C"+startRow+":C"+endRow+"),1),)",,,,,,,
"=rept(char(9733),(round(arrayformula(sum(len(J"+startRow+":J"+endRow+")-len(SUBSTITUTE(J"+startRow+":J"+endRow+",char(9733),""))))/counta(J"+startRow+":J"+endRow+"))))&rept(char(9734),5-(round(arrayformula(sum(len(J"+startRow+":J"+endRow+")-len(SUBSTITUTE(J"+startRow+":J"+endRow+",char(9733),""))))/counta(J"+startRow+":J"+endRow+"))))",
"=rept(char(9733),(round(arrayformula(sum(len(K"+startRow+":K"+endRow+")-len(SUBSTITUTE(K"+startRow+":K"+endRow+",char(9733),""))))/counta(K"+startRow+":K"+endRow+"))))&rept(char(9734),5-(round(arrayformula(sum(len(K"+startRow+":K"+endRow+")-len(SUBSTITUTE(K"+startRow+":K"+endRow+",char(9733),""))))/counta(K"+startRow+":K"+endRow+"))))",
"=rept(char(9733),(round(arrayformula(sum(len(L"+startRow+":L"+endRow+")-len(SUBSTITUTE(L"+startRow+":L"+endRow+",char(9733),""))))/counta(L"+startRow+":L"+endRow+"))))&rept(char(9734),5-(round(arrayformula(sum(len(L"+startRow+":L"+endRow+")-len(SUBSTITUTE(L"+startRow+":L"+endRow+",char(9733),""))))/counta(L"+startRow+":L"+endRow+"))))",
"=rept(char(9733),(round(arrayformula(sum(len(M"+startRow+":M"+endRow+")-len(SUBSTITUTE(M"+startRow+":M"+endRow+",char(9733),""))))/counta(M"+startRow+":M"+endRow+"))))&rept(char(9734),5-(round(arrayformula(sum(len(M"+startRow+":M"+endRow+")-len(SUBSTITUTE(M"+startRow+":M"+endRow+",char(9733),""))))/counta(M"+startRow+":M"+endRow+"))))",
"=countif(N"+startRow+":N"+endRow+",\"=Yes\")/(countif(N"+startRow+":N"+endRow+",\"=Yes\")+countif(N"+startRow+":N"+endRow+",\"=No\"))",,,,,,,,]]
```

Can anyone help me see what I'm missing? I've tried removing different sections of it and can't seem to pinpoint the problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because of the quotation marks `""`. You can:

- escape the marks `\"\"`
- use single quotes `'` to delineate your strings `endRow+',char(9733),""))))/counta(J'+startRow`
- use [template literals](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#template_literals) (e.g. `` `${endRow},char(9733),""))))/counta(J${startRow}` ``)